# Passar dados de um Datagridview em um Form para ComboBox em outro Form

Tags: c#, combobox, datagrid

bom estou com problema que faz dois dias que não consigo resolver , bom vou explicar:

1 -  tenho uma `datagridview` com as informações do banco de dados.

2 -  essas informações ao clicar na linha da `datagridview` ela abre outro form com os campos de *text* e um *combobox*.

3 - ao clicar ele vai passas todas as informações da `datagridview` para o os compo *text* e *combobox* , só que a *combobox* ela não puxa a informações certas.

4 - preciso de ajuda por favor podem ajudar , estou a mais de dois dias procurando uma solução e não encontro

código:

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
 {
        FrmCadastroCadBairro frmb = new FrmCadastroCadBairro();
        //AO CLICAR NA LINHA CHAMA OS DADOS DO BANCO DE DADOS
        frmb.txtcodigo.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        frmb.cbbcidade.SelectedValue = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        frmb.txtbairro.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        //COLOCA O BOTÃO ADD  EM DISABLE
        frmb.alterabotoes(2);
        //E ABRE A JENELA
        frmb.ShowDialog();
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Código abaixo deve resolver o seu problema

```
  frmb.cbbcidade.SelectedIndex = frmb.cbbcidade.FindString(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
```

OBS: Certifique-se que o combo está carregado antes.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda , depois de publicar uns minutos depois eu descobrir o problema kkk , era por que estava carregando os dados , quando eu entrava em outro form ele carregava por isso que não estava puxando os dados da datagridview, mas o que voce colocou ai , tbm funciona obgd!